# open links in a popup with jquery

Tags: jquery

I found some code that i think is what i am looking for but its not fully working. The php file has 10 urls and it echos one of them randomly. What I am trying to accomplish here is to have the url load in a popup window and after 60 seconds reload the popup window with a new url from the php file.

```
<button id="fullurl">open window</button>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
function loadurl(){
    $.getJSON('links.php?json', function(data){
        $('#fullurl').popupWindow('src', 'http://' + data.url, { height:500, width:800, top:50, left:50 }); 
        }
    );
}
</script>
```

Comment: I am trying to load a url in a popup window but nothing opens

Comment: Hmm, I took a look at the `popupWindow` plugin, and it seems it binds a `click()` to the link (`#fullurl`) in your case, so the window won't automatically be opened. If you insist on using this plugin you could `.trigger()` the click on the link in the callback function of your `$.getJSON` call, like so: `$('#fullurl').popupWindow([your options etc]).trigger('click')`. But of an ugly solution, but it should work...

Answer (score 1):

You are requestin `json` ..  is your PHP really returning JSON data ?

if not just use `$.get`, otherwise you should need a key to access the url from the `data` returned ..

something like

```
$.getJSON('links.php?json', function(data)
        {
            // ----------------------------------------------vvvv
            $('#fullurl').popupWindow('src', 'http://' + data.url, { height:500, width:800, top:50, left:50 }); 
        }
```

For the repeating part, use `setInterval` like this

```
setInterval( loadurl, 60000);
```

---

**Update**

You seem to be using the http://swip.codylindley.com/popupWindowDemo.html plugin so make sure to include that in your page.

Comment: i have what you put there but i think my issue is loading the window i click the button and nothing appears. i added my full code by the way.

Comment: @sarsar, besides using the correct plaugin (*updated answer*), it seems that the plugin does not return a handle to the window, so you can't really change the url of the opened window (*since you do not have access to it..*)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `popupWindow` is fully functional already, you could just use a simple `setInterval()` to periodically execute your `loadurl()` function. This also assumes that the `popupWindow` re-uses the same window to load the content in:

```
$(function() {
   // set up the interval, assign it to a variable so we can dispose of it if needed with var.clearInterval();
   var loadUrlInterval = setInterval(loadUrl, 60000);

   // call loadUrl once since the interval will only start kicking in after 60 seconds
   loadUrl();
});
```

Comment: thank you for helping i think my issue is loading the window now :( i added my full code.